# How do I "use Linguist to perform language detection" on my gitHub page?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I'm using GitHub pages to make my website.

I'm using Atom to edit the markdown, and the markdown-preview-enhaced package to preview the result.

So when I write a code like

````
```Java
class Teste{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Hivemind");
    }
}
```
````

It stays perfectly colorized on my preview, but when I push the page to github the code block is not colorized.

I searched for a solution and found that [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks).

Apparently I have to "use Linguist to perform language detection"

> We use Linguist to perform language detection and to select third-party grammars for syntax highlighting. You can find out which keywords are valid in the languages YAML file.

But I dind't understand what that means, and can't manage to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the tool used to render your static site on GitHub pages.

It you are [using Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/), then since 2016, syntax highlighting for fenced code [would be assured by rouge since 2016](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0/#the-highlight-zone).

See [this issue](https://github.com/chrisbobbe/jekyll-theme-prologue/issues/20#issuecomment-598721922)

> I was having the problem where Rogue didn't seem to do anything at all (not wrapping code keywords in `<span>` elements, so there would be nothing to style for the Pygments stylesheet).
>
> Then I discovered [jekyll/jekyll#3641 (comment)](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3641#issuecomment-182182216), removed `highlight: rouge` from the root of `_config.yml` and add `syntax_highlighter: rouge` underneath the `kramdown` node instead:

```
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

You would then use `java`, not `Java`.
Linguist is for [language detection, not syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53709148/6309).